# How can I allow users of my website to upload media files?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm currently following a tutorial for a basic media file upload form. I've tried adding it to my website, but I always get the message "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"  when I try to upload images using it.

I've put the following html file onto my server:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>


<head>
</head>


<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

I have then created the file uploader.php, which looks like this:

```
<?php

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "../uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

I've stored these files in the same directory. I've then created another directory called uploads - which is writable.

Why is this not working?

EDIT: I'm now able to upload files upto 1MB in size, but anything larger than this fails to upload. As you can see in the HTML script, I've set the max file size to 10MB - so this should work. Any idea why it isn't?

Comment: **uploads** folder is in same folder where this code is written or out of this folder ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder.

Comment: Then, give `$target_path = "uploads/";` instead of this `$target_path = "../uploads/";`

Comment: I've tried that already, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the error you get from PHP?

Comment: There is a good explanation of how to [upload files using PHP here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) Oddly enough it in the PHP manual

Comment: You are not checking that the `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` actually exists i.e. a file was selected by the user! You are not checking if `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` is set i.e. was the upload of the file successful. Do all that and then worry about putting the file IF IT EXISTS somewhere

Comment: The probable issue is that your server has a smaller size limit for uploaded files than your test server. Look at the `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` and the error code will tell you what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will Work. I checked in my desktop.

Change `value="100000"` to `value="1000000"`

Like

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
```

And,

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
```

> The **MAX_FILE_SIZE** hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede
>   the file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted
>   by PHP.

For more info, click [File Upload - php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

**User's Requirement** (As, He asked in comment)

Append your file name with `time()`. There are many ways to do. But, this one you can use.

```
$target_path = $target_path .time() .basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm now able to upload files through the website. The only other problem that seems to have arisen is that it always uploads files with the same name, and overwrites the original. For example, I uploaded an image and it uploaded it with the name 'image.jpeg'. I then uploaded a different image, and it also uploaded it with the name 'image.jpeg' - overwriting the previous image. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: And, as I am seeing your SO Profile. You asked total 13 questions and you selected only 2 answers (including this one, *Got Lucky*). So, It comes from both the hand. You should reward them by clicking the appropriate answer. They give you their time by helping all yours questions, which is some time tricky. *Hope You Understand..!! Cheers..* @user2910074

Comment: Sorry, I've only recently realised that this was possible! I've now started making sure I do so. I will go back and do it for those which I had not.

Comment: *That's The Spirit..* Glad To Help. *Cheers..!! Enjoy..!!* @user2910074

Comment: One more question - is there a limit to the filesize that cannot be exceeded (even by adding zero's to that variable)? I've found that I'm currently only being able to upload certain files.

Comment: Through trial and error, I've discovered that I'm unable to upload anything over 1mb. However, I've input the value 10000000, which is 10mb - so it should work, right?

Comment: I have given u the link in my answer. Please go through that. You have to do changes in PHP.ini or htaccess file @user2910074